# Mysql current version not supporting 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, inner-join

I have a table `table1` `o_id` as `PK`,  `host`, `b_id`

```
o_id    host              b_id
9205    host1.abc.com     null
9206    host2.abc.com     null
9207    host3.abc.com     null
```

---more than 1000 rows

I have another table `table2` `id` as `PK`,  `hostname`, `b_id`

```
id      hostname              o_id   ip
18356   host1                 null   10.10.10.10
18357   host2                 null   10.11.11.11
18358   host3                 null   10.12.12.12
```

---more than 1000 rows

Now, if `hostname(excluding domain name)` matches in both tables and `ip` address in range `('10.10|10.11')`, then I want to update both tables such that `table2.o_id = table1.o_id` and `table1.b_id = table2.id`

```
update table1 T1
inner join table2 T2 on T2.hostname = substring_index(T1.host, '.', 1)
set T2.o_id = T1.o_id , 
    T1.b_id = T2.id
where T1.b_id IS NULL AND
 T2.ip IN (select ip from table2 where ip regexp ('10.10|10.11')
limit 10);
```

Here I want to update `o_id` in second table from the `o_id` in first table.
I also want to update `b_id` in first table from `id` in second table.

Here, I am getting an `error`

```
Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I am using MYSQL Versin 6.0

Comment: `regexp ('10.10|10.11')` does not mean range. what about '192.169.10.10` or `192.10.11.255` or not that obvious `192.210.11`?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do an additional `join` instead of `in`:

```
update table1 T1 inner join
       table2 T2 
       on T2.hostname = substring_index(T1.host, '.', 1) join
       (select distinct ip
        from table2
        where ip regexp ('10.10|10.11')
        limit 10
       ) t3
       on t2.ip = t3.ip
set T2.o_id = T1.o_id , 
    T1.b_id = T2.id
where T1.b_id IS NULL ;
```